# NJS-098: 2 positional bind values are required but 1 were provided oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I have upgraded the nodejs vesion from 14.x to 18.x . As part of this change upgrdaded the node oracledb version to "6.2.0". when i try to query the from oracle db its throwing following error

[ERROR]: ERROR null Unable to execute query: Error: NJS-098: 2 positional bind values are required but 1 were provided []

Package.json:

"devDependencies": {
"@types/oracledb": "6.0.4",
"typescript": "4.3.5"
}

"dependencies": {
"oracledb": "6.2.0",
}

**Query :**

const sql =  `SELECT id,name,(select max(days) from days d where id =:0 ) as "days" from test d  WHERE d.id = :0`

const metadata = await db.findOne(sql, [Id]);

Comment: Assuming you upgraded from node-oracledb 5 to 6, you would now be using the new "Thin mode" by default. If you add a call to [`initOracleClient()`](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#enabling-node-oracledb-thick-mode) to enable "Thick mode", then you will get the old behavior and binding will be handled by Oracle Client libraries.  But either way, the suggested answer of using named bind variables is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The [Using Bind Variables documentation](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html) states:

> If a bind parameter name is repeated in the SQL string, then bind by name syntax should be used.

So you should use named bind variables:

```nodejs
const metadata = await db.findOne(sql, {"0": Id});
```

But you may be able to repeat the variable if you are using an array of positional bind variables:

```nodejs
const metadata = await db.findOne(sql, [Id, Id]);
```

(But using named bind variables is recommended.)